# Android localhost to hotspot wlan0 UDP port not accesible

Tags: networking, wifi-hotspot, busybox, udp

I have a drone remote that has android in it. It has an internal telemetry server that is publishing data on localhost:14445 via UDP. When I open the hotspot from this device and connect to it with my computer I'm getting the usual 192.168.43.xx type of IP address. I can ping internal IP addresses of the remote (other than 192.168.43.xx form, for example, devices attached to eth0 interface with IPs like 192.168.144.xx) so I have some sort of access to internal IP's from the hotspot.

But I cannot communicate with the internal UDP port I mentioned before. As Wireshark shows, something is blocking the UDP connection between hotspot and internal IPs.

I tried port forwarding and it didn't work but I don't know if I did it correctly.

I have busybox and root access, please help me. I can give further information upon request.